# MySQL use openSSL / Enterprise Encryption

Tags: mysql, installation, rsa, enterprise

I'm triing to install the MySQL enterprise plugin openssl_udf. I need it for generating RSA keys and RSA encryption. I got the openssl_udf.dll from Oracle and tried the following codes with failures.

```
INSTALL PLUGIN openssl_udf SONAME 'openssl_udf.dll'
```

Failure:

```
Error Code: 1126. Can't open shared library 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib\plugin\openssl_udf.dll'
```

And:

```
CREATE FUNCTION asymmetric_decrypt RETURNS STRING
    SONAME 'openssl_udf.dll';
```

Failure:

```
Error Code: 1126. Can't open shared library 'openssl_udf.dll' (errno: 193 )
```

Does someone know how to use it?

Sources:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/install-plugin.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enterprise-encryption-installation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was simple after all.
After deinstalling MySQL Server (Community) the first time, I didn't delete ALL MySQL files and folders manually, so that the Enterprise installer must have installed the Community distribution again. After deinstalling and removing all files and than reinstalling, everything works fine.